# Relaunch self with special chars not working, without special chars it does

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Trying to have a script relaunch itself in order to get it to immediately hide as I am giving the user a forms based gui with a powershell oneliner, however if there are special chars in the filename itself I cant get the relaunch to work. There can be special chars in pathing all the way up to the filename but not if they are in the filename itself.

Anyone know a way around this?

A cmd file using an & in the name is enough to make it fail.

*EDIT: I think the %cmdcmdline% environment var may be messing up the passed quotes

```
REM Request Admin if not, Generates UAC prompt
CALL :ELEVATE
IF /I NOT "%~dp0" == "%ProgramData%\" (
    COPY /Y "%~f0" "%ProgramData%"
    CALL START /MIN "Test Window" "%ProgramData%\%~nx0">nul
    EXIT /b
)
ECHO MADE IT!
PAUSE
EXIT /b

:ELEVATE
>nul 2>&1 REG ADD HKCU\Software\classes\.thisFile\shell\runas\command /f /ve /d "CMD /x /d /r SET \"f0=%%2\"& CALL \"%%2\" %%3"
>nul 2>&1 FLTMC|| IF NOT "%f0%"=="%~f0" (cd.>"%ProgramData%\elevate.thisFile"&START "%~n0" /min /high "%ProgramData%\elevate.thisFile" "%~f0"&EXIT)
>nul 2>&1 REG DELETE HKCU\Software\classes\.thisFile\ /F &>nul 2>&1 del %ProgramData%\elevate.thisFile /F /Q
EXIT /b
```

Comment: I advise that you change `IF NOT "%~f0"=="%ProgramData%\%~nx0"` to `IF /I NOT "%~dp0" == "%ProgramData%\"`

Comment: Don't keep the "special characters" secret! Tell us the filename so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Magoo an & will do, added that to op

Comment: @Compo seems like better logic, updated in op, ty

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the `Start` command is needed here: `CALL START /MIN "Test Window" "%ProgramData%\%~nx0">nul`. You `Call` a batch file or internal label, not a command. What is wrong with `START "Test Window" /MIN %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C ""%ProgramData%\%~nx0"" 1>NUL`.

Comment: @Compo I want the script to proceed to the next line without waiting an close the original window

Comment: Instead of reiterating your intent, read the Command Prompt output from `[ENTER]`ing `CALL /?`.

Comment: @Compo I can probably remove it, I was experimenting before I posted the question it seems unnecessary but also unrelated

Comment: What is  `/r` option for `CMD` supposed to do? Is that not supposed to be `/c`?

Comment: It's an old flag that does the same thing but Windows freaks out a bit less over it allowing you to prompt for UAC without security immediately flagging the command.

Comment: But you haven't used `/c` or `/k`. We do not know what your inital arguments are, or their exact content either!

Comment: The registry key is immediately available and passes the value ;) to %f0% not %~f0

Comment: @Compo for reference %f0% gets re-assigned to the key each time :ELEVATE is called so it stays correct between relaunches as long as it is called prior

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the question I just didnt see it. The elevate function/sub uses a registry key to pass along the filename during a relaunch in a way that preserved special chars. The same trick can be used in the section I was stuck on as well. So I combined them.. with the added benefit of a single relaunch instead of possibly two.

Example:

```
REM Copy to %ProgramData% and relaunch, request Admin if not, Generates UAC prompt
CD.>"%ProgramData%\reload.thisFile"
>nul 2>&1 REG ADD HKCU\Software\classes\.thisFile\shell\runas\command /f /ve /d "CMD /x /d /r SET \"f0=1\"& CALL \"%%2\" %%3"
IF /I NOT "%~dp0" == "%ProgramData%\" (
    COPY /Y "%~f0" "%ProgramData%"
    >nul 2>&1 FLTMC && START "USE THE GUI TO SELECT A FILE" /min "%ProgramData%\reload.thisFile" "%ProgramData%\%~nx0" || IF NOT "%f0%"=="1" (START "USE THE GUI TO SELECT A FILE" /min /high "%ProgramData%\reload.thisFile" "%ProgramData%\%~nx0" & EXIT /b)
    EXIT /b
)
>nul 2>&1 REG DELETE HKCU\Software\classes\.thisFile\ /F &>nul 2>&1 del %ProgramData%\reload.thisFile /F /Q
ECHO MADE IT!
PAUSE
EXIT /b
```